# Cart price rule discount description does not displayed on cart page in magento

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

The cart price rule "Default Rule Label" and "Store View Specific Labels" are not displayed in the cart. (see screenshot) However the labels are nicely displayed in the confirmation email and on the invoice.

Youd should expect the description displayed between brackets after Discount (where you see now as an example in red 'no label'

I have search an hour on the internet, but I couldn’t find a proper fix or solution. Anybody an idea how to solve this?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For display the **Discount Description** in cart page you need to  override the `Magento_SalesRule` module js file and html template in your theme

**Step 1:** First Create `Magento_SalesRule` folder in your theme

**Step 2:** override the `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/discount.js` file in theme `your-package/your-theme/Magento_SalesRule/web/js/view/summary/discount.js` and put below code in this file

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ],
    function (Component, quote,total) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_SalesRule/summary/discount'
            },
            totals: quote.getTotals(),
            isDisplayed: function() {
                return this.isFullMode() && this.getPureValue() != 0;
            },
            getTitle: function() {
                var title=total.getSegment('discount');

                if (!this.totals()) {
                    return null;
                }
                return title.title;
            },
            getCouponCode: function() {

                if (!this.totals()) {
                    return null;
                }
                return this.totals()['coupon_code'];
            },
            getPureValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals() && this.totals().discount_amount) {
                    price = parseFloat(this.totals().discount_amount);
                }
                return price;
            },
            getValue: function() {
                return this.getFormattedPrice(this.getPureValue());
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**Step 3:** For display Discount Description in cart override the `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html` file in theme `your-package/your-theme/Magento_SalesRule/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html` and put below code

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="totals">
    <th colspan="1" style="" class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text:  getTitle()"></span>
        <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponCode()"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount" data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}">
        <span><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Step 4:** For display Discount Description in checkout override the `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/summary/discount.html` file in theme `your-package/your-theme/Magento_SalesRule/web/template/summary/discount.html` and put below code

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="totals discount">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
        <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponCode()"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': name}"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer #1 is no longer necessary. This has been addressed apparently by vanilla Magento, probably part of the Magento 2 upgrade.

Just specify a **Default Rule Label** under the **Labels** section and that text will show when the automatic cart rule is applied!